# If I wake up before dawn, do I wash my hands with a blessing?

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing

If one wakes up in the middle of the night or at least before dawn, does he wash and make *al netilat yadayim*? Also, at what point can one say *birkot hashachar*? I'd like to wake up extra early to do some study before Shacharit. Additionally, is there a separate ruling for one who wakes in the middle of the night for a glass of water?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/waking-up-in-the-middle-of-the-night

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One who wakes up before dawn (alos hashachar) should wash netilas yadayim without a bracha (Shulchan Aruch OC, 4:14).

Getting out of bed in the middle of the night has the same halacha as getting up before dawn. [In fact this applies even after awakening from a nap during the day.] One should wash netilas yadayim without a bracha. Even if it is just to get a drink, it is preferable not to walk even four amos (6-8 feet) without washing.

Birchos Hashachar may be said from Alos Hashachar. But the custom today is to recite them at arrival to shul in the morning (Shulchan Aruch OC, 46:1-2).

Comment: What if one wishes to learn some Torah before going back to bed?

Comment: So is it fairly safe to say that until _alot hashachar_, no further blessings need be said? For example, as @David mentioned, can I study Torah?

Comment: Birchas Hatorah is more complicated. In truth, most berachos of birchos hashachar may be said before alos hashachar; just we like to wait until afterwards so they can all be said together. If one wakes up at night and wants to learn Torah, he should make a bracha (Shulchan Aruch 47:13), but after going back to sleep and waking again in the morning, there are two opinions regarding whether to make another bracha or not (see Shulchan Aruch 47:11); the Mishna Berura (47:29) believes one should make another beracha.