# Does one make Birkas Hatorah/Hashachar before alos hashachar?

Tags: halacha, blessing, zemanim, netilat-yadayim-washing, tikkun-chatzot

As per [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/if-i-wake-up-before-dawn-do-i-wash-my-hands-with-a-blessing) question, it seems apparent that one doesn't make the morning blessings until at least *alos hashachar*.

However, in Rabbi Avraham Greenbaum's book "The Sweetest Hour: Tikkun Chatzot," on page 31-32, he says:

> Those intending to engage in Torah study after Chatzot should recite *Birkhot HaTorah*, the blessings over the Torah, and they may also recite *Birkhot HaShachar*, the Morning Blessings, if they wish.

Is there a difference in the halacha of hand-washing and morning *berachos* if one gets up for Tikkun Chatzos?

Comment: Rabbi Avraham Greenbaum holds classes every week online from Jerusalem, and posts them on Youtube. He has a group of haverim who receive this via email. He usually discusses deeper meanings of the parsha every week. They are very approachable, so you might try directly from him. Here is his Youtube chanel, you could write him directly.http://www.youtube.com/user/rabbigreenbaum    If you find out, let us know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the procedures of Tikkun Chatzos, but the following may help:

- We re strict to wash our hand for ruach ra'a after sleeping even if it's not the morning ([S.A. O.C 4:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=17)).  No bracha is said on any washing for ruach ra'a unless it is the wash for tefilla.
- Generally birchos hatorah covers you until you go to sleep at night (stam daas).  If one goes to sleep at night and then wakes up to learn, he must say birchos hatorah (whether he says it again when he wakes in the morning- one may rely on either saying or not).  ([S.A. O.C. 47:13 and M.B.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=152))

  If Tikun Chatzos is just a seder tefilla, birchos hatorah need not be said.
- All the brachos may be said even if you wake up in the middle of the night, except for asher nasan (hanosen) lasechvi. However, if you plan on going back to sleep, you may still make all the brachos except asher nasan (hanosen) lasechvi, and you should also say hamaavir sheina without shem umalchus and elokai- neshama without the end bracha. These should be recited in full when you finally wake up. ([S.A. O.C. 47:13 and M.B.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=153))

Comment: There's a bracha on the wash for tefila? Do you mean _al netilas yadayim_ in the morning?

Comment: Unless one studies the subject well, it is common to misapply some of the laws.  There are 2 morning wash ideas (which may be combined):  Washing for ruach ra'a, and washing for tefilla.  Ruach ra'a, as well as other things done for danger like mayim acharonim do not require a bracha.  Washing for tefilla does.  So, for example, one may wake up and wash right after waking, but rewash after the morning routine for davening and say a bracha then (or in shul).  There are other differences which should probably be done by opening a new question if you wish.