# Can I say the prayers of Birkot HaShachar and Tikkun Chatzot after Chatzot (Midnight), even if I don't sleep yet?

Tags: halacha, blessing, sleep, shema, tikkun-chatzot

Can I say the prayers of Birkot HaShachar and Tikkun Chatzot after Chatzot (Midnight), even if I had not gone to sleep yet?
How should I proceed with the Kriat Shema Al Hamitá if I will remain awake after midnight?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Nicolas, and thanks for the interesting question, which would be improved by your including in it an explanation of what motivates he question. (For example, why do you think not having slept should affect whether you say a _b'racha_?)

Comment: Related/dup?: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20710/when-i-wake-up-before-alot-hshachar-and-wont-go-back-to-sleep-what-can-cant-i

Comment: Thank you, I see only now your response. What motivates me in this is that if I pass the midnight I could not say the blessing (Baruch ata adonai eloheinu...) I would like to know if I can do the kriat Shema al hamita, and so after the midnight do the tikkun chatzot and birkot hashachar.