# Do We Repeat the Prayers for Using the Restroom and Washing the Hands After Each Time?

Tags: halacha, blessing, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

I cannot quite figure out whether we are obliged to repeat the blessing over use of the restroom and the washing of hands each time. At present I do in the morning, when I first wake up, per what my siddur notes to do. However, should I commit these to memory and do them each time?

Comment: After each use of the restroom, you should wash and then recite *Asher Yatzar*. However, you do not recite the blessing *Al N'tilas Yadayim* after each hand-washing.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9760/ and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1173/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch 7:1 writes that, throughout the whole day, if one uses the bathroom (gedolim or ketanim) one recites asher yatzar every time, but al netilas yadaim is said only one time in the morning (upon waking up). There are more intricate halachos concerning if one has the runs what should one do about asher yatzer: see Mishna Brurah 7:1.

There is an opinion which holds that if when uses the bathroom (gedolim) and afterwards plans on davening then he would have to make an al netilas yadayim, however the Mishna Brurah writes we don't veer from the Shulchan Aruch's ruling and we recite al netilas yedayim only once daily.

Answer (score 0):

I found another source, right under my nose. The Koren Sacks Siddur states simply, in it's "Laws of Daily Prayer" #320, that this blessing should be performed after relieving oneself every time. I would assume this follows the Shulchan Aruch, as noted above.